# Is there anyway to short this PHP script. random number generating and sorting?

Tags: php

I wanna generate five single random numbers and also wanna sort those numbers. So, I have made a script as follows. Since, I am very fresher in PHP. I made a script very lengthy. Is there anyway to short this code; all help will be much appreciated.

**no sort() and asort() function**

My CODE;

```
<?php
$a = mt_rand(0,9); 
$b = mt_rand(0,9); 
$c = mt_rand(0,9); 
$d = mt_rand(0,9); 
$e = mt_rand(0,9); 

$array=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

echo "Unsorted array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);


for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j ++) {
for($i = 0; $i < count($array)-1; $i ++){

    if($array[$i] > $array[$i+1]) {
        $temp = $array[$i+1];
        $array[$i+1]=$array[$i];
        $array[$i]=$temp;
    }       
}
}
echo "<br />";
echo "Sorted Array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: check out my solution using insertion sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this

```
$array = array();

$array2 = array();

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){

    $array[$i]= mt_rand(0,9);
    $array2[$i] = $array[$i];
    $j=$i;
    while($j>0 && $array[$j]<$array[$j-1])
    {
        $temp = $array[$j];
        $array[$j]=$array[$j-1];
        $array[$j-1]=$temp;
        $j--;


    }
}
print_r($array2);
print_r($array);
```

The above sorting is insertion sort.

Now $array2 represents the unsorted array and $array represents the sorted array. I have made a slight edit to the while loop also. please check this.

Comment: works well. but this only displays sorted array. how to display unsorted array then ?

Comment: `print_r($array);` this doesn't displaying sorted array now

Comment: @Csharp_Newbie i have made a slight change to the while loop.maybe you didnt notice it. please check it

Comment: `Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 [3] => 5 [4] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 [2] => 5 [3] => 2 [4] => 8 ) ` this is the ouput i got. no sorting

Comment: @Csharp_Newbie  sorry. I forgot to add $j-- inside the while loop. it works now. Sorry for the inconvenience. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with no sorting required. Assuming you want it from low to high.
**Edit**: Which, of course, doesn't work if you want to cap the numbers between 0 to 9...You could tweak the amount added to $n to get what you want. Maybe `$n=mt_rand(0,2)`

```
$a = array();
for ($i=0; $i<5;++$i) {
 $n = mt_rand(0, 9);
 if ($i != 0) {
   $n += $a[$i-1];
 }
 array_push($a, $n);
}
```

Comment: `print_r($a)` is to display sorted array. what i should use to display unsorted array ?

Comment: print_r($a) is used to display any type of variables, arrays, - sorted or unsorted. See - http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: There is no unsorted array in my answer. The way the array is generated is such that it started out sorted.

Comment: @extrakunL i wanna display unsorted array first then sorted array. please edit your answer to display like this

Comment: There is no unsorted array. If your intend is to have an incoming array, sort it and display it, then this is not the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = mt_rand(0,9); 
$b = mt_rand(0,9); 
$c = mt_rand(0,9); 
$d = mt_rand(0,9); 
$e = mt_rand(0,9); 

$array=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

echo "Unsorted array is: ";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

asort($array);

echo "<br />";
echo "Sorted Array is: ";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[image]

Comment: i dont wanna use sort() and asort() function

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

echo "Unsorted array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);

sort($array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: i dont wanna use sort() and asort() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of PHP's built in array sorting functions to do that.

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Seems like the one you want is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php

If you're trying to home your skills doing it by hand let me know.

Comment: i dont wanna use sort() and asort() function

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to generate the values and then use the [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function to sort the array:

```
$num_rand_values = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $num_rand_values; $i++)
  $array[] = mt_rand(0,9);

echo "Unsorted array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);

sort($array);

print_r($array);
```

### Demo

Comment: i dont wanna use sort() and asort() function

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array();
for($a = 1; $a<= 5; $a++) {
    $array[] = mt_rand(0,9);
}
echo "un sorted array";
print_r($array);

sort($array);
echo "sorted array";
print_r($array);
```

**RESULT**

```
un sorted array
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
)
sorted array
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 6
)
```